# SNMP monitoring & Web interface

Tags: php, node.js, linux, monitoring, snmp

I have read many articles, forums and informations about SNMP.
Even though I struggle with my project.

The goal of my project is to display data that I get from SNMP on a web page. (Nice designed interface). SNMP protocol is compulsory. And it should run on linux server (I want to add more devices in a final part of project e.g. router, switch.)

Could anyone tell me some quick info what has to be done (step by step review)?

I would be glad for every help. I am confused about what is the best way.

Ajax/database/websockets/traps?

I would like to use PHP or Node.js if it possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a similar project for my internship :

I'm using Perl script for back-end with `Net::SNMP` for snmp request,

Perl CGI for front-end,

and JSON for DB.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a framework to create the web interface, for example Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/) in python.

Then you could use a python library (*pysnmp* will be great) to retrieve the SNMP data, and create a custom View to show this data in a web page.

If you want to stick with PHP, you can use the functions described here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.snmp.php to access the SNMP server, and again using a framework will be great (Laravel, Symfony ...)